# Dart language support in IOS and Chrome

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, dart

I'm exploring Dart an exciting new language from Google and I might create a simple web application using this language.

My friend at Google told me there is quite a bit of energy around this project but I have some questions about its VM before I dive into the project.

Do Dart applications run natively on the Chrome for android and IOS devices? Its wicked fast on chrome for desktop, but the future is mobile. What support do those mobile browsers offer?

Comment: offtopic but cant help to partly answer the question. They have a dart2javascript feature, making it run on all other browsers. If it runs natively on mobile chrome, I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do Dart applications run natively on the Chrome for android and IOS devices?

Currently, no, but there is a fork of Chrome(ium) called [Dartium](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dartium/) that can natively run Dart code, yes.

For all other browsers, however, you can use `dart2js`, which compiles your Dart code to JavaScript:

https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch04-tools-dart2js.html

Comment: In addition, currently iOS developer's TOS does not permit the Dart VM to be ported. This is the same reason that Chrome on iOS cannot use v8

Comment: Interesting, did not know that.

Comment: apple wants a slow web : (